# How can I get a list of every assembly, namespace, and class resolved through reflection in my application?

Tags: c#, ios, visual-studio-2012, mono, unity-game-engine

I need to use a iOS build setting in Unity3d that strips unused classes from bytecode but as it uses static analysis to discover which to remove- so any classes resolved through reflection will not be excluded from removal unless explicitly added to an exclusion list. I managed to remove all uses of reflection in my own code, but Mono itself seems to use a reflection based configuration to do a bunch of stuff and I've already added about a dozen classes to the exclusion list but now I'm to the point where exceptions are not giving any clues as to what class needs to be excluded for them to work.

My question is, is it possible to get a precise list of all the classes (with source assembly and namespace) resolved through reflection throughout every assembly that the application uses, and how would you go about it? I have Visual Studio 2012 and while I know it has powerful debugging tools I don't know how I would use them to this end.

Thanks.

Comment: If your program compiles to one file, just use `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()`

Comment: Not sure why this was down voted. Also I need to list all the classes in a file so ideally I want a list of classes resolved through reflection only.

Answer (score 1):

**The short version**

You can't as there is no way to find all lookups via reflection using static analysis.

**The long version**

Just think of the following example: I write code that selects a class depending on user input, e.g. in pseudo code:

```
string action = ... ; // get some user input here, e.g. "Fire"

string clazz = "Do" + action;

var obj = Activator.CreateInstance("MyActions", clazz);
```

As you can see the actual full class name is not occuring anywhere in the code. So you would need to execute the code in every possible way to find out which values the *clazz* variable could assume. Therefore you cannot find out which classes this code would access via reflection.

**Further Questions**

What exact API from Mono are you using and what kind of exceptions are you getting? Maybe there is some alternative that could be used for your purpose.

Comment: I don't need to use static analysis to find the lookups.

Comment: Well, what I meant to say is that there is no way to find out unless you run your code in all possible ways - which is impossible to do. Could you provide more details about which Mono API is giving you trouble?

Comment: Probably System.Net and System.Configuration. I don't think I would need to execute it every possible way- would the classes selected really vary that much between executions on the same platform with no code changes?

Comment: That very much depends on the code. Could you provide one of the exceptions that you're seeing?